# Centrar una Tabla con TCPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

Tengo que imprimir una tabla con `TCPDF`, pero quiero que en la impresión se visualice al medio (centrada), no puedo usar `css` (porque la librería no las interpreta) y tampoco me sirve el `$tcp->multicell()`, ya que la ubicación en mi página varía según el contenido. ¿Alguno ha podido solucionar este tema?.

```
$pagina.='
<table border = "0" style="">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;" > </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
```

Comment: Es absolutamente necesario que uses tcpdf?

Comment: Si, por experiencia, justo en este sistema me conviene usar la librería tcpdf.

Comment: Ok, y cual es el problema que tienes, podrías colocar un ejemplo de lo que deseas obtener?

Comment: Y si en lugar del html, utilizas Cell y las coordenadas x,y para posicionar los elementos? https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_004/

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar esta solución:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width:25%"></td>
<td style="width:50%"><table><tr><td>Your content</td></tr></table></td>
<td style="width:25%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Saludos,